# Menu Item always null

Tags: java, android, menu, menuitem

```
MenuItem refresh = menu.findItem(R.id.refreshservice);
if (refresh.getActionView()!=null)
{
    refresh.setActionView(null);
}
else
{
    refresh.setActionView(R.layout.refreshicon_nonstatic);
}
```

The Problem is that the MenuItem is always null no matter what I try. The id is correct.

Comment: It would help to see the menu layout and where you are calling this code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this in your Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.refreshservice:
```